# How does iMessage preserve viewController state after view disappears?

Tags: ios, imessage

I observed that iMessage preserves last typed message in a chat even if I move to another chat and come back to it.

For eg. I am in Chat1 and typing. Then without sending the message I move to Chat2 and then come back to Chat1. Last typed message is still there.

If I understand correctly, when I press back button in Chat1, it should execute `viewWillDisappear` which should destroy all local elements.

Then how is last typed message still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iMessage is not the only app which does it. Whatsapp also does it. Even you open a chat in whatsapp scroll to older message->go back->and come again on the same chat. You will see the old state of chat.

The Recommended way to do it is `App State Restoration` if you want to store the whole state of your controller with more UI elements and values.

You can check following tutorial available for this..

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial
>
> http://useyourloaf.com/blog/state-preservation-and-restoration/